# I want to update a column_A based on Column_B (String_DDMONTHNAMEYEAR) value in mysql. Column_B is dynamic

Tags: mysql

I want to update a Column_A based on Column_B_DDMONTHNAMEYEAR value in mysql.The challenge here is the Column_B has dynamic name.

Trying to automate the below update query.

**Update test set Column_A = (CASE when Column_B_DDMONTHNAMEYEAR = 0 then "ZERO"
when Column_B_DDMONTHNAMEYEAR =10 then "TEN"
else "OTHER" end );**

Every month beginning the table test get dropped and create with Column_B_DDMONTHNAMEYEAR.
,where the DDMONTHNAMEYEAR will be last day of previous month.

When the table test created in August then the column name is  <>_31JUL2021
likewise if the table created in September the column name is <>_31AUG2021

Comment: That seems like a bad table design

Comment: Dynamic column names? No. Separate out the data and store it in a table with the 'column name' as a value in a column. It'll be so much easier to query and manipulate it.

Comment: Agree with you - nacho. A legacy system is generating and maintained as like this. We are currently trying to pull some data from it on monthly basis.

Comment: Tangentially Perpendicular - could you elaborate how to achieve this , please? We are trying to pull some data from the table which is generated by a legacy system.

Comment: Are you working on SQL or are using a programming language like Python?

Comment: I am using  SQL - mysql DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is a suboptimal design decision, one way to resolve the situation would be to build and execute a statement within a stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER ;;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS MonthlyUpdate;;
CREATE PROCEDURE MonthlyUpdate()
BEGIN
    SELECT CONCAT('UPDATE `test` SET `Column_A` = (CASE WHEN `Column_B_', UPPER(DATE_FORMAT(Now(), '%d%b%Y')), '` = 0 THEN "ZERO" WHEN `Column_B_', UPPER(DATE_FORMAT(Now(), '%d%b%Y')), '` = 10 THEN "TEN" ELSE "OTHER" END);') INTO @sqlStr;
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sqlStr;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END ;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Then you can call the procedure like this:

```
CALL MonthlyUpdate();
```

You will probably want to build on this, first confirming that the dynamic column name exists, *then* running the prepared statement, but that's outside the scope of this answer.